# Artifactory apache2 proxy on domain root

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, artifactory

I'm trying to proxy artifactory under my domain but I can't get it to work on the domain root, just `/artifactory`.

I want artifactory to be accessible at `http://repo.example.com`, not at `http://repo.example.com/artifactory` like it's forcing me to do.

Here's what I've tried and it should work (by my understanding of `mod_proxy`:

```
ProxyPreserveHost       On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

It proxies me to the right location, but for some reason, artifactory wants to add another `/artifactory/` to the end. Here's what I get when going to `http://repo.example.com:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "/artifactory/artifactory"
  } ]
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Setting Custom Based URL as described [in the docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifactory#ConfiguringArtifactory-CustomURLBase) might help.